# Аналоги if и switch?

Tags: c++, функции

У меня есть функция и нужно вычислить её значение. 
Но загвоздка в том что нельзя использовать операторы `if` и `switch`.  Какие оператори можно использовать вместо них?

Моя функция: f(x)={x^2,x≤0; ln(x), x>0}.

Comment: Тернарный оператор? Условия не очень понятны...

Comment: "Вместо них" использовать *какой-то другой* оператор. Во многих случаях можно обойтись без ветвления вообще. Вопрос слишком общ и потому бессмыслен.

Comment: Как на счет `while (x) {... break;}` вместо `if (x) {...}`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, благодарен, вы мне очень сильно помогли.

Comment: Если бы не 0, можно было бы воспользоваться тем, что `(fabs(x)+x)/2` равно 0 при `x<=0` и `x` при `x>=0`, а `(x-fabs(x))/2` - наоборот.

Comment: @AnT тоесть слишком общий, как тогда исправить чтобы его можно было понять всём (и что вопрос не заблокировали) ?

Comment: Мне кажется от вас ждут одну строчку -- `return x > 0 ? log(x) : x * x;` (а если вычислять вне функции, то такое -- `#define F(x) ((x) > 0 ? log(x) : (x) * (x))`)

Comment: @avp где же вы раньше были?)
Уже поздновато ответ дали.

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда -)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря HolyBlackCat я понял что вместо :

```
if (x) {...}
```

можно использовать:

```
while(x) {...; break;}
```

ёще поискав на просторе интернета я нашёл статейку в которой пишет:

> ...оператор ? для замены if/else...
>
> Оператор ? называется триадным оператором, поскольку ему требуется три операнда и он имеет следующий вид:
>
> выражение1 ? выражение2 : выражение3
>
> где выражение1, выражение2 и выражение3 - это выражения.

Сайт откуда взята информация:
*http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/operator-0*